# how to convert a ros subscriber image into an open cv image?

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I have a program that detects laser points that I know works when I read an image from video 0 but I do not know how to make the program work from a ros subscriber image. I need to know how to convert a ros image subscriber into a usable opencv image named "image" I have researched how to do this and I have come across several solutions that all use the function bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2 but I can not get this to work I am sure it is a simple fix I just don't know what I am doing. This should be relatively simple though. here is my code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
from imutils import contours
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import message_filters
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo
from std_msgs.msg import Int32, Float32MultiArray
import rospy
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError


import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('my_package')
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

'''
def getPoint(cameraTip,dotXY,normalPoint):
    slope= (cameraTip[2]-dotXY[2])/(cameraTip[1]-dotXY[1])
    b=cameraTip[2]-(slope*cameraTip[1])
    z=slope*normalPoint[1]+b
    return [normalPoint[0],normalPoint[1],z]
'''
class image_converter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic_2",Image)
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("CM_040GE/image_raw",Image,self.callback)

    def callback(self,data):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)

        (rows,cols,channels) = cv_image.shape
        if cols > 60 and rows > 60 :
            cv2.circle(cv_image, (50,50), 10, 255)

        cv2.imshow("Image window", cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)

        try:
            self.image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image, "bgr8"))
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)

    def main(args):
        ic = image_converter()
        rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
        try:
            rospy.spin()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Shutting down")
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main(sys.argv)
image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image_message, desired_encoding="passthrough")
while(1):



    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
        #threshold the image to reveal light regions in the
        # blurred image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        # perform a series of erosions and dilations to remove
        # any small blobs of noise from the thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=4)
        # perform a connected component analysis on the thresholded
        # image, then initialize a mask to store only the "large"
        # components
    labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
    mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")

        # loop over the unique components
    for label in np.unique(labels):
            # if this is the background label, ignore it
        if label == 0:
            continue

            # otherwise, construct the label mask and count the
                # number of pixels 
        labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        labelMask[labels == label] = 255
        numPixels = cv2.countNonZero(labelMask)

                # if the number of pixels in the component is sufficiently
                # large, then add it to our mask of "large blobs"
        if numPixels > 300:
            mask = cv2.add(mask, labelMask)
    # find the contours in the mask, then sort them from left to
    # right
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = contours.sort_contours(cnts)[0]

        # loop over the contours
    for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
            # draw the bright spot on the image
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        #x and y center are cX and cY
        cv2.circle(image, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),
            (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
        #camera.release()
```

Currently the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lazerSub2.py", line 18, in <module>
    roslib.load_manifest('my_package')
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 167, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 211, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 203, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: my_package
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/robot/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Comment: A simple Google search would have found http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

Comment: I have looked at that page and tried to do that solution but it is not working could you please tell me what is wrong with what I am doing because that is what I am trying to mimic @fmw42 if you had looked at my code you would see that I am trying to copy that

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I just pointed you to that reference.

Comment: You have a few problems, both before and after you changed your code. 
To begin with, you're importing too much for this code snippet, and you don't need roslib, especially not to load your package manifest. That shouldn't be useful in this case, and is creating the error shown. 
Now you have `image = bridge ....` and `while(1):` floating in the middle of your program. Is this block of code supposed to be a function? 
Separate out the function that process the image from the function/class/stuff that processes ros, then strip out any imports you don't need.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure it's skimage, might have to use scikit-image

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted to do, separate out the ros and the cv components. Your first error was when you were mixing the ros types badly with cv processing. If you throw the ros stuff into a main/main class, keep all of the ros types there, and your functional processing elsewhere.

```
''' image_converter.py '''
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from imutils import contours
from skimage import measure

'''
def getPoint(cameraTip,dotXY,normalPoint):
    slope= (cameraTip[2]-dotXY[2])/(cameraTip[1]-dotXY[1])
    b=cameraTip[2]-(slope*cameraTip[1])
    z=slope*normalPoint[1]+b
    return [normalPoint[0],normalPoint[1],z]
'''
# Image Processing functions
def convert_image(image): # Image of kind bgr8
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
        #threshold the image to reveal light regions in the
        # blurred image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        # perform a series of erosions and dilations to remove
        # any small blobs of noise from the thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=4)
        # perform a connected component analysis on the thresholded
        # image, then initialize a mask to store only the "large"
        # components
    labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
    mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")

        # loop over the unique components
    for label in np.unique(labels):
            # if this is the background label, ignore it
        if label == 0:
            continue

            # otherwise, construct the label mask and count the
                # number of pixels
        labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        labelMask[labels == label] = 255
        numPixels = cv2.countNonZero(labelMask)

                # if the number of pixels in the component is sufficiently
                # large, then add it to our mask of "large blobs"
        if numPixels > 300:
            mask = cv2.add(mask, labelMask)
    # find the contours in the mask, then sort them from left to
    # right
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = contours.sort_contours(cnts)[0]

        # loop over the contours
    for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
            # draw the bright spot on the image
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        #x and y center are cX and cY
        cv2.circle(image, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),
            (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
        #camera.release()
    return image

# ROS Interface
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import rospy
    from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
    from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
    bridge = CvBridge()
    def show_img(cv_image):
        (rows,cols,channels) = cv_image.shape
        if cols > 60 and rows > 60 :
            cv2.circle(cv_image, (50,50), 10, 255)
        cv2.imshow("Image window", cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)
    image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic_2", Image)
    def callback(data):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
            show_img(cv_image)
            cv_image2 = convert_image(cv_image)
            image_pub.publish(bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image2, "bgr8"))
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
    image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("CM_040GE/image_raw", Image, callback)
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
    rospy.spin()
    print("image_converter: Shutting down")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the code gave me a different error I made a new post about it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414858/making-a-laser-detector-have-an-error-in-my-code