# making a laser detector have an error in my code

Tags: python, opencv, camera, ros

I am making a program that detects lasers and circles and numbers then with the opencv library. This is my first time using ros indigo and I don't really know what I am doing but I am getting an error that is repeating at a rapid rate when I run my program. this is the error I am getting:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1565273888.861720] bad callback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "lazer3.py", line 89, in callback
    cv_image2 = self.convert_image(cv_image)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

the error is in the line that says `cv_image2 = self.convert_image(cv_image)` and it is because I use the self if I delete self I get a different error:

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1565274017.459066] bad callback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "lazer3.py", line 89, in callback
    cv_image2 = convert_image(cv_image)
  File "lazer3.py", line 29, in convert_image
    labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'label'

here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
from imutils import contours
from skimage import measure

'''
def getPoint(cameraTip,dotXY,normalPoint):
    slope= (cameraTip[2]-dotXY[2])/(cameraTip[1]-dotXY[1])
    b=cameraTip[2]-(slope*cameraTip[1])
    z=slope*normalPoint[1]+b
    return [normalPoint[0],normalPoint[1],z]
'''
# Image Processing functions
def convert_image(image): # Image of kind bgr8
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0)
        #threshold the image to reveal light regions in the
        # blurred image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        # perform a series of erosions and dilations to remove
        # any small blobs of noise from the thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=4)
        # perform a connected component analysis on the thresholded
        # image, then initialize a mask to store only the "large"
        # components
    labels = measure.label(thresh, neighbors=8, background=0)
    mask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")

        # loop over the unique components
    for label in np.unique(labels):
            # if this is the background label, ignore it
        if label == 0:
            continue

            # otherwise, construct the label mask and count the
                # number of pixels
        labelMask = np.zeros(thresh.shape, dtype="uint8")
        labelMask[labels == label] = 255
        numPixels = cv2.countNonZero(labelMask)

                # if the number of pixels in the component is sufficiently
                # large, then add it to our mask of "large blobs"
        if numPixels > 300:
            mask = cv2.add(mask, labelMask)
    # find the contours in the mask, then sort them from left to
    # right
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    cnts = contours.sort_contours(cnts)[0]

        # loop over the contours
    for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
            # draw the bright spot on the image
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ((cX, cY), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        #x and y center are cX and cY
        cv2.circle(image, (int(cX), int(cY)), int(radius),
            (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.putText(image, "#{}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 15),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
        #camera.release()
    return image

# ROS Interface
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import rospy
    from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
    from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
    bridge = CvBridge()
    def show_img(cv_image):
        (rows,cols,channels) = cv_image.shape
        if cols > 60 and rows > 60 :
            cv2.circle(cv_image, (50,50), 10, 255)
        cv2.imshow("Image window", cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(3)
    image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic_2", Image)
    def callback(data):
        try:
            cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
            show_img(cv_image)
            cv_image2 = self.convert_image(cv_image)
            image_pub.publish(bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_image2, "bgr8"))
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
    image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("CM_040GE/image_raw", Image, callback)
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
    rospy.spin()
    print("image_converter: Shutting down")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

also I want to make it clear that just because the code is the similar this is not a repeat of my last question because I was getting a different error and I was asking about a completely separate issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to *not* have the `self` in there, as `convert_image()` is a regular function. 
The real error is that `measure` has no `label` attribute/function. Except, (depending on the version), [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) exists as you say.

Based on other SO solutions to this (no attribute in module) problem, try checking that the version of skimage you're using has measure.label, try deleting any .pyc files, and make sure you have no naming conflicts or modules with the same name as what you're trying to import.

Edit: 
skimage v0.9.x has the `label` function under the [`morphology`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/api/skimage.morphology.html) module: [`skimage.morphology.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.9.x/api/skimage.morphology.html#label). It was moved to `measure` at a later date.

Comment: I think you may be right that its an version error scikit-image==0.9.3 however I am trying to update it and am having some trouble I am getting this error when I try to Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scikit-image
Storing debug log for failure in /home/robot/.pip/pip.log

Comment: the way I am trying to updating it is  sudo pip install --upgrade scikit-image

Comment: It should be fine if you use the right module, see edits. Pip can also take care of it if you adjust your requirements.txt.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what edits is and I don't know what requirements.txt is

Comment: do you know how I can upgrade scikit image

Comment: You don't need to upgrade, just use the `morphology` module instead. 
'Edit' was just me documenting I changed my answer.
`from skimage import morphology` `labels = morphology.label(...)`

Comment: I sorry what do you want me to do can you explain that better? @JWCS

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want me to do @JWCS

Answer (score 1):

If the function `convert_image` is a method of a class, then you would normally do

```
# instantiate the class
my_obj = my_class()

# call the class' method
my_obj.convert_image(paramaters)
```

so `cv_image2 = self.convert_image(cv_image)` should be `cv_image2 = my_obj.convert_image(cv_image)`

If you aren't instantiating a class, and just calling a function, then you can just get rid of the `self` - `cv_image2 = convert_image(cv_image)`

Comment: As i said before I did get rid of self and it gives me a different error @ron g